# Convert datatype uint16 values from gatt service output to number or decimal in typescript (ionic 4)

Tags: typescript, bluetooth-lowenergy, ionic4, data-conversion

Im working on a project to connect a digital bluetooth ble weight scale device with ionic 4 app using cordova plugin (ble central), i can connect to the device and get all information of the gatt services and even notify and read all of them, but the problem here im having troubles to convert the data from Uint16 (the official doc of the device says the weight scale measurement is on uint16 data type) to a decimal number.

here's a example of the official docs about the wight scale measurement:

Weight Scale Measurement (Uint16):

-example: 123.40 → 0x34 0x30

but if i convert that hex number into decimal i get something like:

-0x34 → 52
-0x30 → 48

the entire value the service gimme back is:

0x02 0x28 0x04 0xE3 0x07 0x07 0x13 0x0B 0x35 0x22

this will be:

-0x02 →  0x01 in lb and 0x02 in kg, in this case the measurement is in kg

-0x28-0x04 → supposed to be the weight measurement value,in this case my measurement was 106.04 kg but if i convert is the value will be 0x28 = 40 and 0x04 = 4

-0xE3 → i don't know

-0x07 → i don't know

-0x07-0x13-0x0B-0x35-0x22 → the date in mm/dd hh:mm:ss

im trying to get the data array buffer and convert in uin8array and then parse into json with this code:

```html
testServiceWeight(deviceId, service_id, charac_id) {
    this.ble.startNotification(deviceId, service_id, charac_id).subscribe(
      data => {
      var buffer = new Uint8Array(data);
      console.log(buffer)
      var serializedData = JSON.stringify(buffer);
      let kg = JSON.parse(serializedData);
       this.value.push(kg)
      },
      err => this.showError(err)
    );
}
```

the output:

{
"0": 2,
"1": 40,
"2": 4,
"3": 227,
"4": 7,
"5": 7,
"6": 19,
"7": 12,
"8": 9,
"9": 10
}

im really stuck here, i dont know how to convert and if the data type is correct.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want to treat your measured value as uint16. 0x3034 is 12340 and 0x0428 is 1064.

Comment: omg thanks very much, the problem here wasnt the conversion, was the order of the array lol, so, i should get the entire array, invert the order of 0x3430 to 0x3034 and convert into uint16 :D, thanks man!!